# What is the most appropriate way to convert nibbles to a u64?

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust and decided to write a program that converts a hex string into a u64.

Currently, I have parsed the string into a vector of u8 values, each representing four bits (or "nibble"). I wrote the following code to take a `Vec<u8>` and return a corresponding `u64`. It works (as far as my testing shows), but I am not sure if it is the "appropriate" way in Rust to go about doing this.

```
fn convert_nibbles_to_u64(values: &Vec<u8>) -> u64 {
    // We need to turn this buffer into a u64 now
    let mut temp:u64 = 0;
    for i in values {
        temp = temp << 4;

        unsafe {
            // We need to unsafely convert a u8 to a u64. Note that
            // the host endian-ness will matter here.
            use std::mem;
            let i_64_buffer = [0u8,0u8,0u8,0u8,0u8,0u8,0u8,i.clone()];
            let i_64 = mem::transmute::<[u8; 8], u64>(i_64_buffer);
            let i_64_be = u64::from_be(i_64);
            temp = temp | i_64_be;           
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I suppose the main issue I don't know how else to cast a `u8` to a `u64` value. Could you comment on ways to improve or write the code in a more idiomatic, Rust-like style?

EDIT:
I have tried the following (unsuccessful) alternatives to the unsafe block:

Or'ing with `i` as a `u64`:

```
temp = temp | i as u64; 
------
Compiler error:
main.rs:115:23: 115:31 error: non-scalar cast: `&u8` as `u64`
main.rs:115         temp = temp | i as u64;
```

Or'ing with `i` directly:

```
temp = temp | i;
------
Compiler error:
main.rs:115:16: 115:24 error: the trait `core::ops::BitOr<&u8>` is not implemented for the type `u64` [E0277]
main.rs:115         temp = temp | i;
```

Comment: What’s wrong with `i as u64`?

Comment: So, out of each `u8` you’re only using four of the bits. So if your bits are `[0b0000AAAA, 0b0000BBBB, 0b0000CCCC, 0b0000DDDD, 0b0000EEEE, 0b0000FFFF, 0b0000GGGG, 0b0000HHHH]` you are wanting to end up with `0bAAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHu64`. Am I correct?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan if input is [0xF,0xE,0xE,0xD,0xB,0xE,0xE,0xF,0xF,0xE,0xE,0xD,0xB,0xE,0xE,0xF], the output should be 0xFEEDBEEFFEEDBEEFu64.

Comment: Using `&Vec<T>` is practically never what you want—it’s two levels of indirection where only one is necessary. You should use just a simple slice `&[T]` instead. If you have a vector `v`, `&v` will coerce from `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]` silently.

Comment: If `values` is too long, `temp << 4` is going to overflow at some point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to convert 8 consecutive bytes into nibbles (encoded in 32 bit integer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259543/fastest-way-to-convert-8-consecutive-bytes-into-nibbles-encoded-in-32-bit-integ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is a simple one: `for i in values`, where `values` is of type `&Vec<u8>`, iterates over *references* to each value; that is, `i` is of type `&u8`. Oring and adding and such with references doesn’t make sense; you need to dereference it, getting the underlying `u8`. The easiest way of doing this is writing it into the `for` loop’s pattern (for the `for` grammar is `for PATTERN in EXPRESSION`, refer to the documentation on patterns for more explanation if you need it; for this simple case, `for &x in y { … }` basically means `for x in y { let x = *x; … }`):

```rust
fn convert_nibbles_to_u64(values: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    let mut out = 0;
    for &i in values {
        out = out << 4 | i as u64;
    }
    out
}
```

The whole form of a loop can be collapsed using `Iterator.fold`, too, like this:

```rust
fn convert_nibbles_to_u64(values: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    values.iter().fold(0, |x, &i| x << 4 | i as u64)
}
```

Comment: Wow so simple, thanks for your help! This is exactly why I post on SO when learning a new language. "You're doing something no one ever does, stop that." Works like a charm, thanks @ChrisMorgan!